# Powershell : Retrying Execution of a function from a catch block in which exception has occured

Tags: powershell, scripting

Please Consider the below Script

```
Function DivNumbers($num1,$num2)
{
    $value = $num1/num2
    echo "Result is : " $value
}
try
{
   $x = 10
   $y = 0
   DivNumbers $x $y
}
catch
{
   $x = 10
   $y = 0
   DivNumbers $x $y
}
```

I am not able to acheive the above , Please suggest me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems unlikely that your intention is to just re-execute the same code that threw an exception.

Comment: Yes Kevin, I have a block of script which sends a mail. The mail sending task is failing often because the web server is very slow and timeout is happening.  I want to send the mail again within the catch block after a wait of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In your above example the flow is as follows:

1. Execute "try" block
2. Head to DivNumbers function
3. Powershell lets you possibly recover by executing "catch" block
   because division by zero occured
4. "catch" executes
5. RuntimeException division by zero occurs and script terminates
6. No chance to reach "echo "Result is : " $value"

The above flow depictor may guide you in solving your particular case.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the DivNumbers function again from catch block ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute it in try/catch block ? In general it's not a good idea to control the flow of script/app using try/catch since it's not meant for that. You should use it for situtaions that are really an Exception - from what I understood your email does not qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead:

```
Function DivNumbers($num1,$num2)
{
    try
    {
        $value = $num1/$num2
        Write-Host "Result is : " $value
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }

    return $value
}

$x = 10
$y = 0
$attempts = 3
do
{
    $value = DivNumbers $x $y
    if ($value -ne $NULL)
    {
        break
    }
    sleep 600
    $attempts--
} while ($attempts -gt 0)
```

Since `DivNumbers` is performing the "dangerous" operation, the `try/catch` should be located within. You can then control flow externally.